# How to enable cookie?

Tags: jquery

Sometimes the browser disables cookies. Although my code needs to set cookie data :

```
Cookies.set('fromAjoutModifDetailsCommande', "<?php echo $dataCommande[0]->commande_id; ?>");
```

Although browser may disable cookies ; so how to enable cookies ?

Comment: if cookies are disabled that's the users choice, you can't enable them in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not possible**, you cannot change browser settings from a webpage.

However what you can do is prompt the user with a alert telling him his cookies are turned off. Let him turn them on before continuing,

Here is how you detect if they are on or off,

```
navigator.cookieEnabled;
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to enable it, if the user blocks cookies you can't enable this, because the user doesn't want. You can look on the internet for plug and play jquery plug-ins to give a message and let the user accept cookies.